# Infinite loop using @axa-fr/react-oidc and keycloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, infinite-loop

I am having multiple issues using @axa-fr/react-oidc with keycloak but the mainly problem now is that is being produced an infinite loop after a login successfull. I put an issue in the library but the solution that have proposed is not working for me. Does anyone have any idea how to solve it or have any example made with this library and keycloak?

This is the configuration of the OidcProvider:

```
const configuration: OidcConfiguration = {
client_id: process.env.APP_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID ?? '',
redirect_uri: ${window.location.origin}/route_of_my_app,
silent_redirect_uri: ${window.location.origin}/route_of_my_app,
silent_login_uri: ${window.location.origin}/route_of_my_app,
scope: 'openid',
authority: 'https://url/realms/app',
service_worker_relative_url: '/OidcServiceWorker.js',
service_worker_only: true,
authority_configuration: {
issuer: 'https://url/realms/app',
authorization_endpoint: 'https://url/realms/app/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
token_endpoint: 'https://url/realms/app/protocol/openid-connect/token',
revocation_endpoint: 'https://url/realms/app/protocol/openid-connect/revoke',
end_session_endpoint: 'https://url/realms/app/protocol/openid-connect/logout',
},
extras: {
response_mode: 'fragment',
response_type: 'code',
}
};
```